# How to get minified output with browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Just started to use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify), but I cannot find documentation for how to get it spilling out minified output.

So I am looking something like:

```
$> browserify main.js > bundle.js --minified
```

Comment: Minification is outside the scope of browserify, you'll need to run it's output through a minifier.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Pipe it through uglifyjs:

```
 browserify main.js | uglifyjs > bundle.js
```

You can install it using npm like so:

```
 npm install -g uglify-js
```

Comment: How to do this with grunt browserify/watchify task?

Comment: If you use grunt I would recommend to do it in two steps. First compile with browserify and then minify. The advantage is that you can have a development build with source maps and a production build that strips everything.

Comment: Yes thats what I ended up doing. Its actually 3 steps, you have to clean up the intermediate file. Thanks!

Comment: and what if i want a sourcemap for my uglified files - that will point to the code before "browserification"?

Comment: Use the `sourceMapIn` option on grunt-uglify (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#sourcemapin) to pass in the source map that browserify created. Be aware of this bug though: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/issues/195

Comment: @ThomasDeutsch I [made a plugin for that](https://www.npmjs.org/package/minifyify).

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate and minify multiple browserify scripts?

Comment: @CMC See Keith Cirkel's blog: http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/  He shows how to join multiple steps together.

Comment: @topek Unfortunately with your solution, I always get this error message: Unexpected token punc «,», expected punc «:»
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:196:18).

Answer (score 22):

As of 3.38.x you can use my [minifyify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/minifyify) plugin to minify your bundle and still have usable sourcemaps. This is not possible with the other solutions -- the best you can do is map back to the uncompressed bundle. Minifyify maps all the way back to your separate source files (yes, even to coffeescript!)

Comment: It says it supports up to browserify version 9.  Browserify is currently at 11.0.1.  Will it support this?

Comment: [uglifyify](https://github.com/hughsk/uglifyify) seems to be working for me as a good replacement

Answer (score 15):

Or use [uglifyify](https://github.com/hughsk/uglifyify) transform which "gives you the benefit applying Uglify's "squeeze" transform before it's processed by Browserify, meaning you can remove dead code paths for conditional requires."

Comment: It still requires using the uglify pipe shown in the top answer. They say so right there in the beginning of their doc.

Answer (score 15):

After spending a few hours investigating how to construct new build processes, I thought others may benefit from what I ended up doing. I'm answering on this old question as it appears high in Google.

My use case is a little more involved than OP asked for. I have three build scenarios: development, testing, production. As most professional developers will have the same requirements, I think it's excusable to go beyond the scope of the original question.

**In development**, I use watchify to build an uncompressed bundle with source map whenever a JavaScript file changes. I don't want the uglify step since I want the build to finish before I've alt-tabbed to the browser to hit refresh and it's not of any benefit during development anyway. To achieve this I use:

```
watchify app/index.js  --debug -o app/bundle.js -v
```

**For testing**, I want the exact same code as production (e.g. uglified) but I also want a source map. I achieve this with:

```
browserify app/index.js  -d | uglifyjs -cm -o app/bundle.js      --source-map "content=inline,filename='bundle.js',url='bundle.js.map'"
```

**For production**, the code is compressed with uglify and there is no source map.

```
browserify app/index.js  | uglifyjs -cm > app/bundle.js
```

**Notes:**

I have used these instructions on Windows 7, MacOS High Sierra and Ubuntu 16.04.

I have stopped using minifyify because it is no longer maintained.

There maybe better ways than what I am sharing. I have read it is apparently possible to get superior compression by uglifying all source files before combining with browserify. If you've got more time to spend on it than I have, you may wish to investigate that.

If you do not have watchify, uglify-js or browserify installed already, install them with npm thus:

```
npm install -g browserify
npm install -g watchify
npm install -g uglify-js
```

If you have old versions installed I recommend you upgrade. Particularly uglify-js as they made a breaking change to command line arguments which invalidates a lot of information that comes up in Google.

Answer (score 5):

I like [terser](https://github.com/terser/terser) which has support for ES6+ and some good comporession as well.

```
browserify main.js | terser --compress --mangle > bundle.js
```

Install globallly:

```
 npm i -g terser
```

Comment: Thanks! This just worked straight up. No fuss like uglifyjs / minifyify

Answer (score 4):

No need to use plugins anymore to minify while preserving a source map:

```
browserify main.js --debug | uglifyjs --in-source-map inline --source-map-inline > bundle.js
```