# How to pass file name/options to Grunt minifyify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browserify, source-maps, grunt-browserify

I'm using the [minifyify](https://github.com/ben-ng/minifyify) plugin as recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23747763/404623) but I can't seem to find any way to pass flags/options to it when used with Grunt.

Here is the relevant part of my Gruntfile:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    browserify: {
        options: {
            browserifyOptions: {
                debug: true
            },
            exclude: [/*...all vendor packages...*/],
            transform: [
                'brfs',
                'debowerify',
                'deamdify'
            ]
        },
        app: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'web/resources/js',
                src: '**/*.js',
                dest: 'web/assets/js',
                ext: '.min.js',
                extDot: 'last'
            }],
            options: {
                plugin: ['minifyify']
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The compiled files are appended to with `//# sourceMappingURL=bundle.map`, which is incorrect. Also, the map files aren't being written to disk or generated at all.

How can I pass options in so that the sourceMappingURL is the same as the file name? So for example:

- `/web/assets/js/foo.min.js` -> `/web/assets/js/foo.js.map`
- `/web/assets/js/bar.min.js` -> `/web/assets/js/bar.js.map`
- and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass options into grunt-browserify plugins/transforms if you pass in the transform as an array with the name as first item, and the options-object as the second:

```
plugin: [['minifyify', {your: 'options'}]]
```

for the transform option it is documented here: https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify#transform

for the plugin-option there is no documentation, but they generally work the same (see `lib/runner.js`, ans search for `options.plugin`)

Comment: Is there a way to pass in the file name as a variable for the options hash?

Comment: you can find the options in the miniffyify-source: https://github.com/ben-ng/minifyify/blob/master/lib/minifier.js#L26. `options.source` is probably what you are looking for (unfortunatly this is not documented)