# How to use Watchify with Uglifyify properly?

Tags: javascript, browserify, uglifyjs

I am looking for a good way to do minification with browserify.

I am developing a react application trying to keep the build setup as simple as possible.

I am using `browserify`, `babelify` and `watchify`.
I do not want to use a task runner like `grunt` or `gulp` but just `npm` in order to keep the setup as simple as possible.

I would like to use the same parameters for browserify (production build) and watchify (during development). The compiled js during development should be exactly the same as in the production build (ie I want minification during development as well. And I want the strongest minification possible with browserify. I know there are other module loaders like rollup or systemjs that achieve even smaller outputs but that's not what I am interested in.

My current `watch` command looks like this:

`watchify src/main.js -t babelify -t envify -o build/bundle.js -v`

the corresponding build command looks like this:

`browserify src/main.js -t babelify -t envify -o build/bundle.js -v`

Note that all the parameters look the same. That's how I want to to be in order to keep the commands in sync in the future.

Now my question is how to add uglification/minification.

I tried adding uglifyify like this: `-g [ uglifyify --no-sourcemap ]` but there are still a lot of line breaks in the output so I guess it's not fully minified.

I also tried removing the `-o` parameter and piping the output throught uglifyjs [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15592279/1533291). This produces a smaller output but it does not work for the `watchify` command.

Comment: Are you aware that the bundle itself won't be minified? Only the modules that go into it will be, so you will see line breaks around code like this `},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){` that wraps each of the minified modules.

Comment: @cartant I was not aware at all that that is the expected behavior. I though I was doing something wrong.  Now that explains alot.

Answer (score 2):

Take note that `uglifyify` runs the squeeze transform from `uglifyjs` but it recommends that you still use `uglifyjs` on the resulting output.

> Uglifyify gives you the benefit of applying Uglify's "squeeze" transform on each file before it's included in the bundle, meaning you can remove dead code paths for conditional requires.

So to change your previous commands to include `uglifyjs`:

`browserify src/main.js -t babelify -t envify -t uglifyify | uglifyjs -cm > build/bundle.min.js`

`watchify src/main.js -t babelify -t envify -t uglifyify -o 'uglifyjs -cm > build/bundle.min.js' -v`

#### Notes

- The `--outfile` / `-o` switch on the `watchify` command is able to accept shell commands as longs as they include a `|` or `>` character.
- As you pipe the results after the bundle stage, `uglifyjs` has to work with the file as a *whole* rather than smaller chunks so you’ll lose some of the speed benefits that `watchify` provides.

Comment: So if I do not have conditional requires uglifyify is not useful at all? Then what's a good way doing code minification that works for both watchify and browserify commands?

Comment: I updated my answer to include the minification steps you were missing. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

**You should not use uglify with watchify**, i had lot of trouble using it together (terminal crash, ram eater) until i read that some minify tools are incompatible with it.

You dont need minify files for development, just use watchify for development, and browserify + uglify for production bundle.

Here are some scripts examples for npm to use browserify and watchify with babel:

```
"scripts" : {
  "build": "browserify -t babelify -t uglifyify ./src/app.js -o ./dist/app.min.js",
  "watch": "watchify -t babelify ./src/app.js -o ./dist/app.js --debug"
}
```

also dont forget your .babelrc file on the root of your project then install this:

npm i -S babel-runtime babel-preset-es2015 browserify watchify

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything. This doesn't minify code at all. It doesn't even remove comments.